# What technologies Google Meet uses for screen and audio/video recording?

Tags: html5-video, webrtc, html5-audio, screen-recording, get-display-media

Now a days since HTML5 is around, neither Flash nor Java is supported by browsers for audio/video recording. As per my knowledge `WebRTC` is leading framework being used by developers to achieve this. In a web based application my client wants to provide audio/video/screen recording. I can quickly think of `WebRTC` as I believe Google Meet uses same. However when digging out little further I realized WebRTC cannot record screen. Then question came to my mind:

What framework is mostly used for audio/video/screen recordings? There are few other web services (for e.g. Loom) they too provided similar interface and allow a/v/s recordings. Please can someone share what framework and technologies these web applications use now a days?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: See [getDisplayMedia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/get-display-media).